# Rails flash messages with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

i started learn HAML: and i can't translate flash block to HAML:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <strong><%= value %></strong>
  </div>        
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you go:

```
= flash.each do |key, value|
  .alert{ :class => "alert-#{key}" }
    %button.close{ :data => { :dismiss => "alert" } } x
    %strong
      = value
```

Just FYI you can add attributes to any element by attaching them as a hash after the declaration. If you don't specify an element, just a class or ID, HAML makes that element a div with the given class or id. But you could do this many ways. For instance, these are all the same:

```
%div{:class => 'foo bar', :id => 'test' }
.foo{:class => 'bar', :id => 'test'}
#test.bar{:class => 'foo'}
#test.foo.bar
```

All output: `<div class="foo bar" id="test"></div>`

You need to put computed attributes in the hash though, i.e.:

```
- klass = "bar"
%div{ :class => klass }
```

Outputs: `<div class="bar"></div>`

Also, note that in all the examples above, the `:attribute => 'value'` can be expressed as `attribute: 'value'`, e.g.:

```
%button.close{ data: { dismiss: 'alert' } } x
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I advise adding this check as well around the content tag as libraries such as Devise adds more then just alerts and notices into this structure.
            -if key == 'alert' or key == 'notice'

Comment: I know this is very old, but still being useful it is advisable to use a `- flash.each` instead of `= flash.each`, otherwise the HAML interpreter will dump out the flash hash into your HTML.