# Writing ruby code in a haml string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Just adopted an application using HAML and trying to write on top of it (never used HAML before). Been looking at different resources like [haml.info](http://haml.info/tutorial.html) and this [S.O post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13978951/2456549). However, the S.O. post is actually incorrect in a couple ways. I'm trying to render your basic bootstrap flash messages.

So far I have this structure:

```
- flash.each do |key, value|
  .alert.alert-dismissable{ :class => 'alert-#{key}' }
    %button.close{ :type => 'button', :data => { :dismiss => 'alert' }, :aria => { :hidden => 'true' } }
      %i.icon-remove-sign
    = value
```

Yea that's right, I have to go back to Bootstrap 2 on this one. Seems like everything works, except this line here:

```
.alert.alert-dismissable{ :class => 'alert-#{key}' }
```

This gets rendered to HTML as

```
<div class="alert alert-#{key} alert-dismissable">
```

Obviously, I want `#{key}` to be replaced with the key coming from the controller (`success`, `danger`, `notice`, etc) Would love to know what is wrong here. Thanks for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"alert-#{key}"`

In ruby you can't use `#{}` to escape single quoted strings.

Comment: Don't I look dumb. Thanks @Baloo. Will accept when I can.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it, I had a similar moment earlier today

Comment: Happens to the best of us.